# prove or disprove that $(0,1)$ and $(0,1]$ are homeomorphic with cofinite topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $(0,1)$ and $(0,1]$ be two subspaces of $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{T}_f)$ where $\mathcal{T}_f=\{U|\mathbb{R}-U {\rm \; is \; finite\; set}\;\}\cup \{\emptyset\}$.

1. Prove or disprove that $(0,1)$ and $(0,1]$ are homeomorphic.
2. Find the interior, closure and boundary of $[0,1)$ and $K=\{\frac{1}{n} \mid n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ in $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{T}_f)$, respectively.

please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Any bijection is a homeomorphism. Finite sets map to finite sets and ditto for inverse images.

Comment: Exercise.  If X and Y are equinumerous and both have the cofinite topology, then prove every bijection between X and Y is a homeomorphism.  For what other topologies is a bijection also a homeomorphism?